# Checking file extension in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fileinfo

I have a script which is supposed to tell the file type (jpg,bmp,png).

The script is as follows:

```
$file="pic/shimla.png";

$finfo = finfo_open();

$fileinfo = finfo_file($finfo, $file, FILEINFO_MIME);

finfo_close($finfo);
```

Now say if I had a file earlier named a.jpg, which later I changed to a.png,
the above script will state that the image is actually jpg, even though it is renamed to a.png

Now I want to do the same with CodeIgniter, and I wonder if CodeIgniter has some own function which can make it equivalent to the above script.

I tried to use CodeIgniter's function `get_mime_by_extension('file')`, but it has a problem.

If I change the a.jpg to a.png, then the above function returns image/png which is not true, it should be a.jpg, just the top-most script does.

So `get_mime_by_extension('file')` just returns the extension of the image, it doesn't evaluate the original nature of the image. if it is renamed to bmp, it will throw bmp, if its renamed to gif, it will throw gif.

Comment: neither way is 100% reliable so if you want to do it your way that you know already works you may as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

```
$result = getimagesize($file);
$mime = $result["mime"];
```